# I am having an error with decryption with the cryptography module

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption

I am writing a password manager, but am getting this error when run all of a sudden, ive tried googling, and couldnt find anything. the code runs, but then suddenly gives an error.
Traceback:

hello, thank you for using APM. enter 'help' for help. enjoy!

```
> find google
"google", "google.com", "AntispleneticMoonlighty", "#{6P=,U{;%^AMO+", "number- 1"

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\CODING\Python\APM.py", line 80, in <module>
    db.decrypt()
  File "D:\CODING\Python\APM.py", line 44, in decrypt
    decrypted = fernet.decrypt(original)
  File "C:\Users\Anton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\cryptography\fernet.py", line 85, in decrypt
    timestamp, data = Fernet._get_unverified_token_data(token)
  File "C:\Users\Anton\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\cryptography\fernet.py", line 121, in _get_unverified_token_data
    raise InvalidToken
cryptography.fernet.InvalidToken
Press any key to continue . . .
```

the code is listed below (trimmed), the error is referring to line 44(shown below):

Code:

```
import PGL
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet
import os
import logging as lg


class APMDatabase:
    def __init__(self, keyfile_path, database_path):
        global start
        self.keyfile_path = keyfile_path
        self.database_path = database_path
        print(start)

 

    def read_key(self):
        with open(self.keyfile_path, "rb") as keyfile:
            return keyfile.read()

    def encrypt(self):
        key = self.read_key()
        fernet = Fernet(key)
        with open(self.database_path, "rb") as file:
            original = file.read()
        encrypted = fernet.encrypt(original)
        with open(self.database_path, "wb") as encfile:
            encfile.write(encrypted)

    def decrypt(self):
        key = self.read_key()
        fernet = Fernet(key)
        with open(self.database_path, "rb") as file:
            original = file.read()
        decrypted = fernet.decrypt(original)            #THIS IS THE LINE WITH THE ERROR
        with open(self.database_path, "wb") as decfile:
            decfile.write(decrypted)
   
    def find(self, name):
        db.decrypt()
        with open(self.database_path, "r") as database:
            content = database.readlines()
            for i in content:
                if name in i:
                    print(i)
                    return i
        db.encrypt()        
    
    

db = APMDatabase(
    keyfile_path="D:\\CODING\\Python\\APMKEY.APMKEY",
    database_path="D:\\CODING\\Python\\APMDatabase.APMDATA",
)

while True:
   db.decrypt()
   number = len((open("D:\\CODING\\Python\\APMDatabase.APMDATA")).readlines())
   db.encrypt()
   
   query = input("> ")
   
   
   elif "find" in query:
       data = query.split(" ")[1]
       if data == "(all)":
           try:
               db.find('"')
           except:
                lg.error("404")
       try:
           db.find(data)
       except:
           lg.error("404")
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Could you give us an example of what are the values of key, plaintext and ciphertext?